# mongodb collection level access control with wildcard

Tags: mongodb, authorization, roles

I am going to have my collections named as 'a', 'a.b', 'a.b.c'... in the format of a package names.
I want to create roles in mongodb like below,

```
db.createRole(
   {
     role: "regexAccess",
     privileges: [
       { resource: { db: "scriptrepo", collection: "a.*" }, actions: [ "find","update","insert","remove" ] }
     ],
     roles: []
   }
)
```

Is it possible to do such a thing in MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use regex in the name of the collections while creating roles. The exact name of the collection's are to be used.

Comment: How did you find out that it is not possible?

Comment: i have tried giving some regular expressions in the name field and it was treated like a string

Comment: Did you log a feature request for this that I can track, or did you just move on?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas did not log any request

Comment: @Joel'-'  [SERVER-22951](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22951) is the issue for this feature and it's open as of this writing.